# IIS 8.5 "Connection was reset" Error on Chrome When Posting, but Works For Get Requests

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2012-r2, iis-8.5

I have been working on an intranet site and recently users have been complaining that when they save a change they get "This site can’t be reached."  The users are using Chrome exclusively as far as I can tell, and when I tested with Edge, I got no errors.  So, I first tested on the web server, I was unable to recreate the issue.  I tried on another server within the network and I was also unable to recreate the issue.  I then tried my pc, which was connected through a VPN and was finally able to recreate the issue.  What is weird is that this just started happening and I haven't updated the site in quite awhile.  The can view most pages and the issue only seems to happen when posting to IIS.  At this point, I am not sure where to start to troubleshoot this issue.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:  Updated the title to show the actual error I got.

Edit 2:  Someone put me on to checking the httperr log and I see an error for the post request with client_reset as the error message. hope that makes the issue a bit more clear.

Comment: IIS itself does not even have a 504 error. So in your case, find your network administrators and locate the source of that error before doing anything else.

Comment: check if you/they have any extensions (like ad blocking, or virus checking) on  chrome

Comment: @LexLi I appreciate that, but the issue is where do I direct them to look?  This is a small company with a single IT person, who is not a network expert.  Is there no way for me to determine what is going wrong with these requests?

Comment: You need to learn tools like Wireshark so as to dive further into the network packets. When you know what happens on the wire, it would be easy to troubleshoot and find out the actual cause.

Comment: @LexLi  Ok, I will take a look at that and see what I find.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue with help from the network security firm the client was using.  Once I was able to confirm the issue only occurred when clients who were using a VPN, he ran some tests.  The issue was that the firewall was blocking posts that seemed suspicious.  Now, this site has been running for years with no issues.  My assumption is that they made some security changes and it caused this problem.  What was odd, was that I tried a few fixes and they would work for a few times and then would stop working, such as using the site ip address versus the domain name.  I hope this helps the next person.

Wade